# Cloud Endpoints backend API not working out of the box

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am following the official tutorial at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints. When I rebuild, and then try to access the endpoint from my client android app. The following classes cannot be found: AndroidHttp, AndroidJsonFactory, GoogleClientRequestInitializer, AbstractGoogleClientRequest, AbstractGoogleJsonClient

Here is the code snippet

```
MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                        new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                        // options for running against local devappserver
                        // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                        // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                        .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                        .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                            @Override
                            public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                                abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                            }
                        });
```

I am also not able to see MyApi. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: can you please post your gradle build file for your Android app

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to backend gradle and it works

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.21'
}
```